# DevExpress XtraReport XRTable Alternative Row Color

Tags: devexpress, xtrareport

Using DevExpress XtraReports - I wish to have alternative colors/styles within the rows in an XRTable like in the Demo Centre example below.

*https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7xKd.jpg*

Answer (score 2):

Set the XRTableRow's Style.Even and Style.Odd properties to the colors you'd like for even/odd rows:

[image: Even Odd styles]

See also: [Report Visual Styles: Even/Odd Styles](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument1303/Odd)